Are 15 amp outlets in the same junction box as a 20 amp outlet acceptable by code?
So I went through a project to add a handful out outlets to the outside of my house, and being one to only do things once I decided it was going to be a 2-gang box, one 20 amp receptacle and one 15 amp receptacle controlled by a dusk/dawn switch (for holiday or accent lighting basically). The 20 amp outlets are the appropriately keyed outlets with the yellow sleeved conductor (12 gauge?) going back to a single circuit with an appropriately rated GFCI and 20 amp breaker as well while the 15 are just the regular "surprised face" outlets with the white sleeved conductor (14 gauge) controlled by 1.) A dusk to dawn sensor and 2.) A separate GFCI on a 15 amp breaker. I wrapped the outlet terminals in electrical tape pre-installation so there shouldn't be a chance of one contacting the other (aside from the physical distance imposed by being mounted in the box).
It only occurred to me AFTER doing all this that this might be a problem, but I wanted to check, is it code acceptable to have differently rated outlets in the same box? And as a bonus question, is there a way I should label these? Either to show they are different amperage ratings OR to show one is switched? I was just going to use a label maker, but if there are standard symbols I might as well follow that.
For more context this is in Wichita Kansas.

Are both on the same breaker?  That's an issue if the breaker is 20 amp. you can't use #14 wire.   Please give details as to what breaker/s feed these outlets.

@RMDman Yeah, they are on separate appropriately sized breakers. Question updated, thank you!

I don't think you mean "different voltages".   And I'm curious: Do you own anything with a 20A 5-20P plug?  I cannot think of any residential appliance with one, and cannot find one for sale anywhere.   They must exist.

@jay613 You are correct, changed to different amperage ratings. And no, I've never actually seen anything with the sideways neutral, but I figure it can't hurt to mark it differently in case I ever do find one.

Yes you can have outlets on different circuits in the same gang box.  You should label the box "Multiple circuits within" especially if they are not handle-tied, so people working inside the box will know to turn off more than one breaker.
You should label the switched outlet, "On Timer" so random people using it won't think it's broken if it's off and you should also label it "GFCI Protected" if it's not obvious (because the GFCI device is somewhere else).   GFCI outlets often come with a few of the latter sticker.

Technically (code language) you only need a handle tie if two things on the same yoke (such as top and bottom of a split outlet) are on different circuits. Not to say labeling is a bad idea. I like my labels to call out which circuit breaker and/or panel the devices are served from, but I'm not normal...

@Ecnerwal That's correct for this question.  Folks should keep in mind MWBC and 240 V have stricter rules for handle ties.

I won't install a 240V circuit unless it's from a bona fide two pole breaker (with common trip), so I never use (mere) handle ties for those. Not a code requirement in all cases, but MY minimum standard.

@Ecnerwal: I'm with you.  A circuit whose breaker is not "on" should not have any potential automatically-actuated connections to any other circuit that might be "on".  Whenever any circuit feeding a device isn't "on", none should be.

For a timer, you're now supposed to use outlets that have been engraved with the on/off icon and the word CONTROLLED. NEC 406.3(E). It's also a thing to mount switched outlets upside down relative to all the others.

$20 for a 1-cent label and they are hard to find.  I wonder, if you mount the specially engraved NEC symbol upside down does it comply? :).
